# Jquery UI Date Picker blank

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

i'm trying to populate a jquery datepicker with a valid date.  the field is always set to blank no matter what value i use.

```
$("#datepicker-myTest").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    });
    var d = new Date();
    var currMonth = d.getMonth();
    var currYear = d.getFullYear();
    var startDate = new Date(currYear, currMonth, 1);
    $("#datepicker-myTest").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker-myTest").datepicker("setDate", new Date(startDate));
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ct1hybL6/  seems to work fine.

Comment: i
I just found out that when you populate the datepicker control, it turns the font white.  As the background was white, the box didn't show a value.  The initial value was MM/DD/YYYY (in black font) to prompt the user.  As soon as i selected a date, it changed the font white

Comment: d is in there to create the startDate object.  Without it, it would throw an error.

Comment: Your original snippet did not have the startDate in the final line.  Also, `startDate` is already a date object.  There's no reason to give it to new Date() at the end

Comment: are you getting any error in the console.

Comment: no.  the resolution is to override the CSS class for the font to not turn the value white.  The value was being populated but the date control turns the font white when it's changed.